# Create a structure from a dynamically assigned <itab>

Tags: abap, rtts

In a method I have a reference to a table that was declared like this:

```
DATA: tabname TYPE tabname,
      dref    TYPE REF TO data,
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <itab> TYPE ANY TABLE.

CREATE DATA dref TYPE TABLE OF (tabname).
ASSIGN dref->* TO <itab>.

SELECT * FROM (tabname)
    UP TO 5 ROWS
  INTO TABLE <itab>.
```

How do I create a structure based on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use good ol' RTTS for that. You can create reference and read directly into it

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <itab> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
DATA: ref_wa        TYPE REF TO data,
      ref_rowtype   TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
      ref_tabletype TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr.

ref_rowtype ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( tabname ).

CREATE DATA ref_wa TYPE HANDLE ref_rowtype.
READ TABLE <itab> REFERENCE INTO ref_wa INDEX 1.
```

or create field-symbol based on this reference and use it in READ TABLE

```
ASSIGN ref_wa->*  TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fsym_wa>).
READ TABLE <itab> ASSIGNING <fsym_wa> INDEX 1.
```

Pay attention I declared `<itab>` as **STANDARD** table to get rid of index error operation you got.

[image]

**UPDATE**: for creating structure from `<itab>` object use this syntax:

```
ref_tabletype ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( <itab> ).
ref_rowtype  ?= ref_tabletype->get_table_line_type( ).
```

The last two lines will be identical.

Comment: Thank you for your pointing. But just trying to master RTTS - can I use this solution with <itab>, not with a name of a dict object?

Answer (score 1):

1.You define a `ANY` field symbol ans use `ASSIGNING`

```
 FIELD-SYMBOLS:
      <line> type any.

 LOOP at <itab> ASSIGNING <line>.

 ENDLOOP.
```

2.You define a `ANY` field symbol ans use `INTO`

```
 FIELD-SYMBOLS:
      <line> type any.

 CREATE DATA dref like line of <itab>.
 ASSIGN dref->* to <line>.

 LOOP at <itab> INTO <line>.

 ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Agreed but I don't see the interest of the solution 2 with CREATE DATA and INTO (more complex, less performant, no advantage)

Comment: @SandraRossi Solution 2 shows how to dynamically define a type of a line of table.  It is just one of the answer to the question. Both INTO and ASSIGNING has its own pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline declaration to define WA like this. `READ TABLE <itab> INTO (<wa>)` or declare WA/Field symbol first using `FIELD SYMBOL <wa> TYPE ANY` then read table with `READ TABLE <tab> ASSIGNING <wa>`

Comment: READ TABLE <itab> ASSIGNING <fs> INDEX row. gives me: You cannot use explicit or implicit index operations on tables with types "HASHED TABLE" or "ANY TABLE". "<ITAB>" has the type "ANY TABLE". It is possible that the "TABLE" addition was not specified before "<ITAB>".

Comment: READ TABLE <itab> INTO (<wa>) INDEX row. gives me: Field "(<WA>)" is unknown. It is neither in one of the specified tables  nor defined by a "DATA" statement. .

Comment: Maybe a typo. Please try `FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs>. READ TABLE <table> INTO <fs> WITH KEY (fld_name) = "value".` This is exactly the code in my program

Comment: FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs>. gives error: Untyped field symbols are not supported in the OO context. Use "FIELD-SYMBOLS ... TYPE ANY". .

Comment: Please take a look at this article https://blogs.sap.com/2014/04/03/create-dynamic-table-using-rtts-and-display-in-alv/